# Dart - Mark as Deprecated Documentation

Tags: dart, code-documentation

I changed something in my implementations and I want to mark some classes deprecated, so  that they will use the new implementations instead.

How can I mark a class as deprecated in dart? For now I only document it as deprecated without actually marking the class or crossing it out.

```
/// Throws a BadRequestException - 400
class BadRequestException implements Exception {}
/// Throws a NotFoundException - 404
class NotFoundException implements Exception {}
/// Throws a ConflictException - 409
class ConflictException implements Exception {}
/// [DEPRECATED]
/// Don't use this anymore, this is deprecated.
class AlreadyExistsException implements Exception {}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Found it. [Deprecated Classes](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Deprecated-class.html)

```
@Deprecated('Use [ConflictException]')
class AlreadyExistsException implements Exception {}
```